# How to serve pdf (or non-image) files through google app engine with python flask?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Here is the code that I currently use to upload the file that I get:

```
header = file.headers['Content-Type']
parsed_header = parse_options_header(header)
blob_key = parsed_header[1]['blob-key']
UserObject(file = blobstore.BlobKey(blob_key)).put()
```

On the serving side, I tried doing the same thing that I do for images. That is, I get the UserObject and then just do 
`photoUrl = images.get_serving_url(str(userObject.file))`.

To my surprise, this hack worked perfectly in local server. However, on production, it raises an exception:

```
    File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/images/__init__.py", line 1794, in get_serving_url
    return rpc.get_result()
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/apiproxy_stub_map.py", line 613, in get_result
    return self.__get_result_hook(self)
  File "/base/data/home/runtimes/python27/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/images/__init__.py", line 1892, in get_serving_url_hook
    raise _ToImagesError(e, readable_blob_key)
TransformationError
```

What is a proper way to store/serve non-image files such as pdf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use the `images` API, that won't work since (at least in production) it performs image content/format checks and you're not serving images.

You can have your own request path namespace with a handler, just like any other handler in your app, maybe something along these lines:

```
def pdfServingUrl(request, blob_key):
    from urlparse import urlsplit, urlunsplit
    split = list(urlsplit(request.url))
    split[2] = '/PDF?key=%s' % blob_key.urlsafe() # rewrite the url 'path'
    return urlunsplit(tuple(split))
```

And in the handler for `/PDF*`:

```
    blob_key = self.request.get('key')
    self.response.write(blobstore.BlobReader(blob_key).read())
```

If you use [the Blobstore API on top of Google Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/#Python_Using_the_Blobstore_API_with_Google_Cloud_Storage) you can also use direct GCS access paths, as mentioned in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/34023661/4495081.

**Note**: the above code is a barebone python suggestion just for accessing the blob data. Additional stuff like headers, etc. is not addressed.

Per @NicolaOtasevic's comment, for `flask` the more complete code might look like this:

```
blob_info = blobstore.get(request.args.get('key')) 
response = make_response(blob_info.open().read()) 
response.headers['Content-Type'] = blob_info.content_type 
response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="%s"' % blob_info.filename
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was very helpful. I think that in the pdf handler you need(because of flask and so that we serve a pdf and not a binary): blob_info = blobstore.get(request.args.get('key'))
  response = make_response(blob_info.open().read())
  response.headers['Content-Type'] = blob_info.content_type
  response.headers['Content-Disposition'] = 'filename="%s"' % blob_info.filename. Do you mind correcting that in your response before I accept it?

Comment: Done. Thanks for the suggestions.