# How to download a video file stored in google cloud storage on my web page?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-storage

I am planning to use google app engine and host my web site. Users should be able to upload video files to google cloud storage and also download from it.

Is there any java script library with which browser can download the video file directly bypassing the app engine?

If it cant be done directly, what are some other approaches?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: While not exactly a duplicate question, this answer might help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/34023661/4495081

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are the videos publicly visible? If so, you can simply have users download the objects directly from GCS by having them fetch the URL "https://storage.googleapis.com/BUCKET_NAME/OBJECT_NAME".

If the objects are private, you can sign the URL to accomplish the same goal.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Nope the videos are not publicly visible. So the java script will download the object and how could I play the video on the browser when the download completes- Is there a way to point video tag to the object?

Comment: Sure. The signed URL is the same as any other HTTP URL. You'd just use <source src="PUT_THE_SIGNED_URL_HERE" type="video/mp4"> inside the <video> tag. Keep in mind that streaming video can be a somewhat complex field, and specialized streaming servers, CDNs, and other technologies can improve performance. But any video file in the cloud works with a basic video tag.

Comment: cool..but is it possible to download the video locally and then point src attribute of video the local file? this is achieve offline support.